# High CPU usage in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I got info from my hosting provider that my below site is using High CPU resources. Basicaly index.php and admin.php site.

URL :

Sometimes it is using more than 150%.

**I have done below steps to optimize the site :**
- Upgraded WP Version with latest one
- Added WP Optimize plugin

**Presently these are the plugins used in site :**
- Colored Tags Tag Cloud Widget
- Comments Facebook and Share Button
- iThemes Security
- MailChimp for WordPress Lite
- Moviral Adsense
- NextGEN Gallery by Photocrati
- Simple Share Buttons Adder
- tagDiv speed booster
- WordPress SEO
- WP-Optimize

URL of site : [siete24.mx](http://www.siete24.mx)

Someone help me to short out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your site using below :

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Do and solve rules suggest by google as per above link use.